# Can other EC2 users network sniff my traffic?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

Is there any way another EC2 user can network sniff the traffic coming from or going to one of my EC2 instances, even if both our virtual instance are on the same physical host?  And because this one is the most sensitive one to me, I will ask specifically, could another EC2 used find a way to sniff the traffic between my EC2 instance and my RDS database?

Comment: Why would they permit that? http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697 *It is not possible for a virtual instance running in promiscuous mode to receive or "sniff" traffic that is intended for a different virtual instance.*

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on EC2, but if Amazon sets up NAT'ed DomU's for separate instances (and I'm sure they do), you should be safe.

With NAT, every instance only receives packets that were intended for that host. So no packet sniffing possible (at least in theory).

I should add that there are some interesting (as in "look we did it and wrote a paper about it") sniffing attacks based on L1 cache sniffing.
[link to paper, if you're interested](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~reiter/papers/2012/CCS.pdf).